# Selected Option Based on Hidden Div Input Value

Tags: jquery, html, hidden, selected

I have a drop-down menu within an ajax generated form.

HTML:

```
<select id="MedicationMonth_row18" name="MedicationMonth[]" style="width: 30px;">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="01">Jan</option>
<option value="02">Feb</option>
<option value="03">Mar</option>
<option value="04">Apr</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">Jun</option>
<option value="07">Jul</option>
<option value="08">Aug</option>
<option value="09">Sep</option>
<option value="10">Oct</option>
<option value="11">Nov</option>
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to add a selected value based on an input value in a hidden div.

HTML

```
<td align="left" style="display: none;">
<input id="MedicationMonthValue_row18" type="text" value="03" name="MedicationMonthValue[]" style="width:30px">
</td>
```

The JS code I am using to try to create a selected option is the following:

```
var medval = $('#MedicationMonthValue_'+id).val();
$('#MedicationMonth_'+id).val(medval);
```

Also tried the following:

```
$('#MedicationMonth_'+id).change(function() { $('#MedicationMonthValue_'+id).val( $(this).val() ); });`
```

When I alert medval, I get the value from the hidden input field.

I have been struggling with this for weeks. Any pointers would be great! Thanks!

EDIT: Here is more complete codes of what I am using that may point out stack issues.

```
$('.trSelected', grid).each(function(){
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');                                
                            for(i=0;i < ($(this).children().length); i++){
                                    if (i == 0) {
                                            var name = $("thead tr").children().eq(i).attr("abbr");
                                            var width = $(this).children().eq(i).children().css('width');
                                            var old_value = $(this).children().eq(i).text();
                                            var new_value = $(this).children().eq(i).html('<div style="text-align: center; width: 40px;"><input type="hidden" name="'+name+'[]" value="'+old_value+'"/>'+old_value+'</div>');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            var name = $("thead tr").children().eq(i).attr("abbr");
                                            var old_value = $(this).children().eq(i).text();
                                            var width = $(this).children().eq(i).children().css('width');   
                                            if (name == 'MedicationMonth') {
                                      var medval = $('#MedicationMonthValue_'+id).val();
                                      $('#MedicationMonth_'+id).val(medval);
                                                var new_value = $(this).children().eq(i).html('<select id="MedicationMonth_'+id+'" name="MedicationMonth[]"><option value="">--Select--</option><option value="01">Jan</option><option value="02">Feb</option><option value="03">Mar</option><option value="04">Apr</option><option value="05">May</option><option value="06">Jun</option><option value="07">Jul</option><option value="08">Aug</option><option value="09">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option></select>');                                                          
                                            }                                                                                         
                                            else {
                                                  var old_value = $(this).children().eq(i).text();
                                                  var new_value = $(this).children().eq(i).html('<input style="width:'+width+'" type="text" name="'+name+'[]" id="'+name+'_'+id+'" value="'+old_value+'"/>');
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                            $(this).removeClass("trSelected");
                            $(this).addClass("trEdited");
                            $("div.fbutton").eq(2).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                            $("div.fbutton").eq(2).css('width', '0px');

                            $("div.fbutton").eq(3).css('visibility', 'visible');
                            $("div.fbutton").eq(3).css('width', 'auto');

                            $("div.fbutton").eq(4).css('visibility', 'visible');
                            $("div.fbutton").eq(4).css('width', 'auto');                               
                    });
```

Comment: When is the code that sets the `select` value called? Since it is an ajax-generated form you need to make sure that piece of code **after** the form is generated, ie, in the callback function.

Comment: Does id contain `"row" + index`?

Comment: It is being called within the ajax related code within the page. Okay, can you provide an example of callback function?

Yes, each id contains row+attr index of the row. example provided above...row18

Answer (score 0):

This code is working:

```
var medval = $('#MedicationMonthValue_'+id).val();
$('#MedicationMonth_'+id).val(medval);
```

You just can't see it because you have a tiny width on your drop down list. Remove the width on your select.

```
<select id="MedicationMonth_row18" name="MedicationMonth[]">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/NSN62/

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code. I tried removing the size attribute in the select code and the selected value still does not appear.

Comment: It's working in the fiddle I linked in my answer. If it's not working on your page, there must be something happening with other code. Perhaps it's an order of execution issue, or something else is failing and preventing this code from running. If you can post more of the code (like the Ajax code you mentioned in another comment and anything else that's running on that page) I can try to help more, but as is what you posted should be working just fine.

Comment: Craig - Yes, it does work, but as you alluded to, it is the placement of the codes, after putting the codes after the select codes, it worked like a charm. Thanks...thumbs up!

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help! Please click the check to mark this as the answer if you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WREdT/1

```
$(function(){
    $('#MedicationMonth_row18').val($('#MedicationMonthValue_row18').val());
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggested codes. I tried putting them in the head section and still no joy. I'll try to post more codes to illustrate what I am attempting to do. I am using Flexigrid with CI if that makes a difference in terms of how things interact. Using Ajax to pull in data into the view.

Answer (score -1):

The ids for any element should always be uniqued on a page. Either change the id of hidden input element or the select element.

Try this

```
   <input id="hid_MedicationMonthValue_row18" type="text" value="03" name="MedicationMonthValue[]" style="width:30px">

    var medval = $('#MedicationMonthValue_'+id).val();
    $('#hid_MedicationMonth_'+id).val(medval);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did not vote you down, however, the element IDs are already unique. So, your suggestion does not help me.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the id's were already unique and the code that was posted in the answer was what he had in his original post. The answer added no useful info for solving the problem.